# Waiting for DOM to load: Cypress

Tags: cypress

I try to make and E2E test with **Cypress**. I have to visit multiple links from a table and make an assertion after visiting the page.

In the Cypress UI I see the page is loaded, also if I check I can see the elements in the DOM. But my Cypress assertion not working, it says:

```html
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: cy.should() failed because this element is detached from the DOM.

<div id="content" class="css-1ddoub">...</div>

Cypress requires elements be attached in the DOM to interact with them.

The previous command that ran was:

> cy.wait()

This DOM element likely became detached somewhere between the previous and current command.
```

My test code:

```js
cy.get('[id="content"').parent().within(()=>{
      cy.get('[data-cy="list-item"]').each(item => {
        const link = item.find('a').first();

        cy.visit(link.attr('href')!)
        cy.wait(5000)
        cy.findByText(/report herunterladen/i)
   })
})
```

**Element exists in the DOM:**
[image]

Interesting because If I hardcode the url and not use .each, then all assertions works fine after .visit().

```js
cy.visit('/de/banks/compare/?a=calculations.average&b=ins.PL.PKO') // Hardcoded url
cy.wait(1000)
cy.findByText(/report herunterladen/i)
```

I tried to use cy.wait() even with a large number like 30000 but it didn't work.

For me it looks like Cypress has a bug with .each() method. It doesn't want to load pages DOM elements within the each function.

Cypress: 10.7.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see this answer [Traverse through a list...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73873696/16997707).

To avoid detached error, use `.each()` on list of urls not list of elements

```js
cy.get('[id="content"')
  .parent()
  .within(() => {
    cy.get('[data-cy="list-item"] a')
      .then($els => [...$els].map((a) => a.href))   
      .each(link => {
        cy.visit(link)
        cy.wait(5000)
        cy.findByText(/report herunterladen/i)
   })
})
```

Comment: Thank you @TesterDick your answer was the closest to solve my problem. It does not solved 100% because when I map through the hrefs I have to store them in an array with cy.task('setHrefs', href) then I can get the hrefs also with cy.task('getHrefs) and visit them one-by-one and it works.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the `cy.visit()` command is over-writing the links on the page.

You should issue a **go-back** to restore them, but also re-query the link elements inside the loop.

```js
cy.get('[id="content"').parent().within(() => {
  cy.get('[data-cy="list-item"]')
    .each((_, index) => {
      cy.get('[data-cy="list-item"]').eq(index)   // re-query after page changes
        .find('a').first().then(link => {
          cy.visit(link.attr('href')!)
          cy.wait(5000)
          cy.findByText(/report herunterladen/i)
          cy.go('back')
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Detached error happens when you successfully saved(e.g. using cy.get()) a DOM element into memory, and tried to access it but the page has unfortunately removed that element meanwhile. To be precise, the page has probably re-rendered(re-created the same elements).

It is OK to put `cy.wait()`, but before you actually try to access the elements.

```js
// Change this number depending on your needs
cy.wait(2000) // Let the page do it's thing

// Now try to access
cy.get('[id="content"').parent().within(()=>{
      cy.get('[data-cy="list-item"]').each(item => {
        const link = item.find('a').first();

        cy.visit(link.attr('href')!)
        cy.wait(5000)
        cy.findByText(/report herunterladen/i)
   })
})
```

The above should work, but you should review this issue on the Front-end and look deeper into the re-rendering cause.

> Detached DOM element error is actually a JS error.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this!

```
 cy.get('[id="content"').parent().within(()=>{
              cy.get('[data-cy="list-item"]').each(item => {
                
             cy.wrap(item).find('a').first().invoke('attr','href').then((href)=>{
                cy.visit(href)
                cy.wait(2000)
                cy.findByText(/report herunterladen/i)
             })   
           })
        })
```

Comment: I tried it. Had to add .should() after the last row: ```cy.findByText(/report herunterladen/i).should('exist')```. It throws an error that the element is not visible. Without the should('exist') it works but then it doesn't check that the element is rendered.

Comment: Make sure that there is only one result with text matching 'report herunterladen' in the dom. cypress may be interacting with the hidden element with the matching text 'report herunterladen'.

Comment: There is no result unfortunately. If there would be more results then it would throw an error because of the multiple same elements.