# Traverse through a list, perform actions and return back to the next item in list

Tags: cypress, cypress-each

Is there a way I can traverse through the list, perform click again and then return to the same page again for the next item in list.

```
cy.get('#collaborators').next().children().each((items) => {
// Here I have to write code to access list element
 cy.log(cy.wrap(items))
}
```

Log gives me a structure like this and am not sure how to access it. Please help as I am new to cypress.
[image: Result of cy.log]

```
cy.get('#collaborators').next().children().each( (items,index)=>{
      cy.wrap(items[index]).click()
    }
    )
```

Having a code written like this, is causing DOM element to be detached although it goes to the next page.

```
var itemsCount = cy.get('#collaborators').next().children().its('length')
```

Not sure if I can loop over to get to each of the elements this way.

Comment: Each time you navigate back to your page with the anchors, the DOM may have changed and will lead to a 'detached from DOM' error.

Answer (score 3):

If you evaluate the `href` attribute before starting the loop, you'll avoid the **detached from DOM** error.

Essentially, iterate over a string array not an element array.

```js
cy.get('#collaborators').next()
  .find('a')                                  // find all <a> within the <ul>
  .then($els => [...$els].map((a) => a.href)) // extract the href
  .each(href => {                             // now iterate list of URL strings

    cy.visit(href)
    cy.pause()                                // substitute whatever test you need 
    cy.go('back')
  })
```

#### Clicking the link

If you prefer to click the link, extract the last part of the `href` and use it to find the link element ***inside the loop***

```js
cy.get('#collaborators').next()
  .find('a')                                    
  .then($els => [...$els].map((a) => a.href))   
  .each(href => {                              

    const slug = href.split('/')[3]
    cy.get('#collaborators').next().find(`a[href="/${slug}"]`).click()

    const title = slug.replace('~', '')
    cy.contains('h2', title)

    cy.go('back')
  })
```

Comment: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.npmjs.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame. This is the error am getting.. not able to go back to the previous page.

Comment: Both tests work for me - what page are you visiting?

Answer (score 0):

cy.children() enables you to select child elements and use the selector to filter them. In your case, to get the *a* tag element, you can do something like:

```
cy.wrap(items).children('a');
```

I am also new to cypress, but I believe you can access the *href* attribute with the *invoke()* command:

**invoke()** - https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/invoke

Try something like this:

```
cy.wrap(items).children('a').invoke('attr', 'href')
        .then((url) => {
            cy.visit(url);
        });
```

Comment: cy.get('#collaborators').next().children().each( (items,index)=>{
      cy.wrap(items[index]).click()
      cy.go('back')
    }
    ) This is how am able to click.. However after click, DOM element is detached and I cannot find a way to traverse through the list again.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice you needed to get back and click again.

Comment: I suggest you make a separate test for each list element, consisting of cy.visit() and click(). Also, a good idea may be to rethink your link selectors, to find not all of them, but each one exactly.