# How do I use cy.each() when each time the page reloads the images?

Tags: cypress

**Desired Outcome:** I would like to write a test that clicks on each of these "X"s. I would like to do this until there are not any images left.

[image: Images]

**Use Case:**

I reload the list of images each time, to ensure I backfill up to 15.

1. The user has 18 images
2. On the first page I show 15
3. When the user deletes 1 image, I reload the images so there are 15 on page 1 again, and now only 2 images on page 2.

**Error:**

Because of the reload of the images, it is causing the `.each` functionality from Cypress to break with the following error message:

> cy.click() failed because the page updated as a result of this
> command, but you tried to continue the command chain. The subject is
> no longer attached to the DOM, and Cypress cannot requery the page
> after commands such as cy.click().

**Cypress Code Implementation:**

```
cy.get('[datacy="deleteImageIconX"]').each(($el) =>  cy.wrap($el).click());
```

What can I do to run a successful test that meets my use-case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen this before, this answer helped me tremendously [waiting-for-dom-to-load-cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73908831/21199911).

The trick is ***not*** to iterate the elements, rather use a loop over the total (18) and to confirm deletion within the loop.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
  cy.get('[datacy="deleteImageIconX"]')
    .first()
    .click()
    .should('not.exist');  
}
```

This strategy eliminates the problems:

- trying to work with stale element references (detached)
- iterating too fast (confirm current action completes first)
- page count being less than total count (page adjusts between iterations)

Comment: How would I know the length? Can I count the length before starting the for loop?

Comment: I assumed you know from setting up the test. Otherwise could  use `cy.get('[datacy="deleteImageIconX"]').its('length').as('count')`